# To hide the button in Classic view and show only in Lightning view

Tags: custom-button, button, salesforce-classic

I need to create a Custom button(Not a VF page button) which will work differently based on the user view ie, Lighting and classic. I need hide the button in Classic view and show only in Lightning view. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display in lightning then "Create New Action" rather than "New button or Link".

You can associate a lightning component to Action.

Answer (score 0):

if you have Created the button as action then don't add it to detail section but do remember to add in Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions section. While Creating quick action, you can use your either visualforce Page or Lightning Component. Hope this information will help you.